# What should I change in this code to solve the differential equations?

Tags: matlab

[I don't understand how the variable has to do anything with the error than I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzR7Q.png)

I changed the variable but to no avail.

Comment: Wht don't you believe the error message ? It is quite explanatory.

Comment: Put all the code beginning with line 12 in a separate file. The rates.m file should only contain the code for the rates( ) function itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add functions to a script, place them at the end of the file. See the Mathworks documentation here: [Add Functions to Scripts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html)